# Powershell - passing by property parameter using Get-ADComputer

Tags: powershell

I am trying to understand why this fails:

```
Get-ADcomputer -filter * | select @{l="computername";e={$_.name}} | Get-service
```

The error returned is 'cannot find service with service name '@{comptuername=SERVER1}'
I can get data when using  | get-service *
However I am trying to understand better why this specific command does not work.It seems that instead of type string, 'computername' is passed as  to Get-servic as  ADcomputerobject?

I expect Get-service to get Computername by Property from pipeline and since Name property for Get-Service in not mandatory, the command above should just work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the incoming object is binding the Name parameter, not ComputerName. Even though ComputerName accepts incoming object by property name, the Name parameter accepts that also but much more important it accepts incoming object by value and that takes precedence over by property, so the incoming objects always fall into the Name parameter.

The object type,  ADcomputerobject, has nothing to so in this case since you can repro with a customobject. You can also get a hint about the problem from the error message (...with service **name**):

```
PS> [pscustomobject]@{ComputerName='server1'} | gsv
gsv : Cannot find any service with service name '@{ComputerName=server1}'.
```